# mysql and not null column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null

i have a address field and null is set to no. but when i insert record to table with empty address field , record added to table. and address column is empty. 
why record add to table despite address empty?

Comment: More details??! This is very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null and empty are two different things, you need to validate with php before sending data to database. ie;

```
if (empty($_POST['address'])) {
}
```

Comment: null and empty ae different? if i dont fill address field , it is empty or null?

Answer (score 2):

Could depend on how you add the data, for example if you entered the string as '' its not null, its just empty.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to insert an empty string into a nullable field.

> Insert into myTable (address) Values
>   ('')

will work even if Address is not nullable.

Check if your field is really null.

> Select * from myTable where address is null